# EQ Settings for iOS Sound Application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio

Ok so I need to have access to eq settings for my application. Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this? I have looked into using ObjectAL but it seems their library is quite limited.

I need control over gain, freq, and q.

If possible control over a low-pass filter, and a high-pass filter.

https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not an easy task. Maybe a look at : http://theamazingaudioengine.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [NVDSP](https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP) with AudioQueues in the past.

Its fairly simple to use and gives you control over gain, center frequency and q factor.

Comment: Thanks! I got his example code working but I am trying to add gain control to his code. On the homepage of the git it gives an example but its saying that I cant use data in place of outData in the gain example  https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP/blob/master/Examples/NVDSPExample/NVDSPExample/ViewController.mm                                                
NVDSP *generalDSP = [[NVDSP alloc] init];
[generalDSP applyGain:outData length:numFrames*numChannels gain:0.8];

Comment: @MatthewScott: What happens when you run applyGain?

Comment: so its working but what is something with -1 gain applied to the sound supposed to sound like? It sounds just like 1

Comment: @foo: Gain is a multiplicative factor.  -1 will sound much like it did to start with (though all the signs of the PCM will be swapped).  To halve the volume set a gain of 0.5 to double set 2.  To convert a dB to a multiplicative factor is done as follows:  gain = powf( 10.0f, (gaindB / 20.0f) ).  Through this you can see that 6dB is, roughly, a doubling in gain.

Comment: Any idea about min and max values for q I couldn't tell the difference from q=0 to q=10

Comment: You are unlikely to see a HUGE difference with a high pass thouh .. try a band pass to see huge differences with the Q factor ...

Comment: The Q factor has to be attatched to a filter?

Comment: How about reverb or decay? doesn't look like NVDSP can do either

Comment: Indeed I suspect its just a set of different coefficients though ... might be worth figuring out what NVDSP is actually doing ...

Comment: @foo: this really should be asked in another question but you can't define things as you do outside of a function.